# c# constructor and streamwriter

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I would like to create a generic logger class. This complains "value cannot be null.Parameter name:path". After I initialize the object I get the logname value but not log. where did I do wrong?

```
class Logger
{

    public static string log;


    public Logger(string logname)
    {
        log = logname;

    }
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(log);
}
```

Comment: For your class, the memory is allocated, the data members are initialized and THEN the constructor is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
    public Logger(string logname)
    {
         log = logname;
         writer = new StreamWriter(log);
    }
    StreamWriter writer = null;
...
```

You have this error because first is executed following line:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(log);
```

And in that moment field log is null because constructor is executed after fields initialization.

Comment: I would note that initializing the `writer` field as `null` is unnecessary; fields are always initialized to their default values.